Flink Checkpoints in S3 - Retention policy
I have a few Flink 1.17 workloads that save checkpoints to S3. They are running on Kubernetes and managed by Flink Operator. I have as well decided to RETAIN_ON_CANCELLATION for safety.
I can see the expected structure in S3:
/user-defined-checkpoint-dir
    /{job-id}
        |
        + --shared/
        + --taskowned/
        + --chk-1/
        + --chk-2/
        + --chk-3/
        ... 

However, the number of files under shared seem to be constantly growing. Some are months old despite the fact that I have a TTL of 1 day max.
Here's an example extracted today (2024-09-05), using LastModified S3 property:
Period starting 2024-07-18: 130545.63 MB
Period starting 2024-07-25: 1014.31 MB
Period starting 2024-08-01: 9.93 MB
Period starting 2024-08-08: 2267.53 MB
Period starting 2024-08-15: 104870.59 MB
Period starting 2024-08-22: 92.28 MB
Period starting 2024-08-29: 95672.27 MB

Is there a way to reliably expire these objects without corrupting the checkpoints?
